# $.removeCookie is not deleting cookie in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, cookies

$.removeCookie is not deleting cookie in Chrome.

Please refer the below attachment of screenshot. The screenshot is taken from the Chrome settings -> All Cookie and site data.

[image]

The above screenshot is clearly showing that one cookie(name : !Proxy!proxyJSESSIONID, and path : /stockquote/rest/auth) is available. But when

```
$.removeCookie('!Proxy!proxyJSESSIONID', { path: '/stockquote/rest/auth'});
```

code is executed it is returning **false** and **not deleting the cookie**.

[image]

I am using **jQuery Cookie Plugin v1.4.1.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have found an alternative.

```
$.cookie('!Proxy!proxyJSESSIONID', '', { expires: -1, path: '/stockquote/rest/auth'});
```

1. Setting the value as blank('') and
2. Set one additional option expires : -1

But **$.removeCookie** is not working.

Answer (score 6):

To delete a cookie with jQuery set the path value to null:

```
$.removeCookie('filter', { path: '/' });
```

Comment: Please refer my description I am using $.removeCookie

Comment: Set the path to '/'. That's what I was refering to

Answer (score 1):

To delete cookie, set it's value for `null`

```
$.cookie("!Proxy!proxyJSESSIONID", null, { path: '/stockquote/rest/auth' });
```

And it would be deleted

Answer (score 0):

Always use path while setting cookies. By default cookies are saved as per pages

```
//Set value to cookie
$.cookie('key', 'value', { path: '/your/path'});

//remove value from cookie
$.removeCookie('key', { path: '/your/path' });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   document.querySelector('#btn3').addEventListener('click', userExit);
    //click func for (unlogin) dellite cookie.
    function userExit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let cookie = document.cookie.split('; ');
        let cookieObject = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < cookie.length; i++) {
            var cookieArr = cookie[i].split('=');
            cookieObject[cookieArr[0]] = cookieArr[1];
        };
        let expDate = new Date();
        expDate.setTime(expDate.getTime() - 1000);
        for (let cookie in cookieObject) {
            let expires = expDate.toGMTString();
            document.cookie = cookie + '=' + '; expires=' + expires + '; path=/';
        };
        location.reload();
    };
```